# How to remove focus border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, focus, border

Can anyone explain how to remove the orange or blue border (outline) around text/input boxes? I think it only happens on Chrome to show that the input box is active. Here's the input CSS I'm using:

```css
input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px solid;
    height: 20px;
    width: 160px;
    color: #CCC;
}
```

[image: Text box with blue outline and "Example" written in it]

Comment: note that oulines also appear in different cases: in IE9 you can see little dots around a button if you select it using tab (ie. you click inside a field before the button & go to the next fields using Tab until you reach the button [going to previous field is Shift + Tab])

Comment: ...And in case someone needs to remove it from select elements in firefox: http://notes.jerzygangi.com/how-to-remove-the-dotted-border-from-around-select-tags-in-firefox/

Comment: Use **border-style: none; background-color: white; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; color: black;**

Comment: As @Torkil-Johnsen mentioned in a comment below, you might want to give a different style to make it more obvious, but to just remove it is very bad for accessibility  (e.g. people who only use a keyboard or other assistive device to tab through elements).

Comment: try this css, it work for me
`textarea:focus, input:focus{ border: none; }`

Answer (score 3214, accepted):

This border is used to show that the element is focused (i.e. you can type in the input or press the button with Enter). You can remove it with [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property, though:

```css
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

You may want to add some other way for users to know what element has keyboard focus though for usability.

Chrome will also apply highlighting to other elements such as DIV's used as modals. To prevent the highlight on those and all other elements as well, you can do:

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

---

#### ⚠️ Accessibility warning

Please notice that removing outline from input is an accessibility bad practice. Users using screen readers will not be able to see where their pointer is focused at. More [info at a11yproject](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20CSS%20rule%20%3Afocus,with%20the%20link%20or%20control.)

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using Chrome, latest update. I put `input:focus {outline: 0;}` in the CSS, but when I type, the blue Mac outline is still there.

Comment: Problem is when you already use outline. For ex : "outline: .5em solid black !important;". Chrome still does something which reduces the width and it also gets rid of the box-shadow which I'm also using.

Comment: Use `outline: none`

Comment: outline-style: none works well with Chromium (version 34) and Firefox (version 30)

Comment: It's bad for accessibility to remove this outline that is default on :focus. This means that users using the keyboard to navigate will have a hard time seeing which link/item is highlighted when they hit tab. If anything, the highlighting of the element should be enhanced to make it *more* obvious which item has focus.

Comment: @TorkilJohnsen, While I agree 100% that the element should be visibly focused the default blue/orange ring behaviour is not always the right strategy.  As long as some strategy is adopted (and adopted consistently across a design system) then CSS should be authored to support that decision.

Comment: This answer promotes creating inaccessible solution which prevents a lot of people from using important applications. Even with the "accessibility warning" at the bottom, most people would not bother to read it below. This answer needs to be hidden or heavily modified so that at the top is an accessible solution and below with a big warning with working like "Previous Answer: Do not use it!" the inaccessible solution.

Comment: Everyone loves to point out the inaccessibility of this. Forgetting that we often work with designers/managers who care little for accessibility. Even after fighting in its corner (in my experience). We all know its bad, but we also need to know answers.

Comment: I have put a lot of care into the visual look of my appllication.  I absolutely do not want it messed up with orange outlines.  I also am, generally, infuriated by systems that assume they know what is best for me, and force me to comply.  I agree with Crispen Smith that we developers should be able to choose our strategy.  If the systems people have nothing to do, they might try fixing all the bugs and anomalies we have to cope with.

Comment: In my case this worked

 border: none;

Comment: This did not work for me on latest Windows Chrome.

Comment: " border: none" did work.

Answer (score 304):

The current answer didn't work for me with Bootstrap 3.1.1. Here's what I had to override:

```css
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: inherit;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: ```box-shadow: none;``` did the trick for me. When I put in on the element without ```:focus``` it also removes a very subtle shadow that Chrome puts on border-less and input boxes.

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason input:focus { outline:none;} did not work.

Comment: This worked for me. I am using FF latest browser and outline: none is not working.

Comment: This solution also works for bootstrap v4.

Comment: On bootstrap 4, if the outline you want to remove is round the hamburger mobile menu, you can just use: <button class="navbar-toggler" style="outline:none;" ...>

Comment: this worked for me on chrome. outline:none did not

Comment: I even had to put `box-shadow: none!important;` to keep bootstrap from added that border box shadow

Answer (score 139):

```css
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

This will do. Orange outline won't show up anymore.

Comment: Instead of  input:focus{ outline: 0; } -> outline:none; Works

Comment: Don't do it unless you provide some other styling, it's important for accesability. see http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: Actually, this CSS isn't enough.  For example, if you're using JQueryUI tabs, the ugly blue border appears after you click on a tab, if you just use your CSS.  You do need to add a:focus or li:focus, to prevent the border.

Comment: this is bad for accessibility and shouldn't be done.

Comment: I am working with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input 
And this solution worked just fine. THanks

Answer (score 76):

```
<input style="border:none" >
```

Worked well for me. Wished to have it fixed in html itself ... :)

Comment: <input style="border:0px" > also works, as well.

Comment: you can triple that: input { border: 0 none transparent }

Comment: When I add border:none to a css class, its still showing the border for the input field.  where as the inline css style="border:none" is working

Comment: @arun8 sounds like your CSS selector isn't the highest 'priority' (forgot the word but its like, the importance of your selector e.g p > span.class is more important than just span.class so it will use the code in p > span.class

Comment: @arun8 you can try using "!important" in your css class

Comment: @brandito the word you're looking for is "specificity"

Answer (score 65):

I've found the solution.
I used: `outline:none;` in the CSS and it seems to have worked. Thanks for the help anyway. :)

Comment: That's the focus outline you are removing. It's there for a reason: Usability. Especially keyboard users will hate it if you remove it.

Comment: @RoToRa what if he crafts a better one using shadows CSS 3 ?

Answer (score 33):

this remove orange frame in chrome from all and any element no matter what and where is it

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

**Solution**

```css
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

PS: Use `outline:0` instead of `outline:none` on focus. It's valid and better practice.

Comment: nope, not working on Chrome

Comment: How is it better practice?  You need to explain why, not just say so.  It's definitely not better practice.

Answer (score 20):

Please use the following syntax to remove the border of text box and remove the highlighted border of browser style.

```
input {
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 0px solid;
    height:30px;
    width:260px;
}
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the transparent definition on the background-color attribute. You don't need that and you probably will have a big problem when you need to write something (you won't find the inputs!).

By the way, personally, I would change the transparent background to select a color. For example, if my container has a red color, I would use a white background on the input.

Comment: For me just outline:none; won't work. But solid 0px solved for me.

Answer (score 14):

This will definitely work. Orange outline will not show anymore..
Common for all tags:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Specific to some tag, ex: input tag

```
input:focus {
   outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Set

```
input:focus{
    outline: 0 none;
}
```

"!important" is just in case. That's not necessary. [And now it's gone. –Ed.]

Comment: Don't use !important unless you REALLY MUST use it.

Comment: @Mackelito You must use !important to work with Bootstrap

Answer (score 13):

I found out that you can also use:

```
input:focus{
   border: transparent;
}
```

Comment: The question may have "border" in the title, but the OP is actually asking about the default outline