# How to disable default box shadow /border-color in Google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The default border color for active input tags in Google chrome is yellow, how do i disable it?
[image]

How do i change the color in css?

Comment: This is good theme.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/3397113/9161635

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the CSS outline property - try `outline:none;` on the form fields.

Comment: You're welcome. It will also remove the dotted outline on links.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two css properties: border or outline.

```
.bordered
{
  border:1px solid your_color !important;
}

or

.bordered
{
outline:1px green solid !important;
}
```

This is because most of browsers has own css rules which you need to override saying to browser my rule is **!important**.

--Edit

You can also press **Ctrl + Shift + I** to display developer tools for Chrome and find css which makes problems.