# Remove Orange Border on Active Menu in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, border

Recently I have been learning **ASP.NET**. I have ran into a slight difficulty which I cannot fix nor find a solution to after hours of trial and error/searching. Now you know I'm not wasting your time, here's the information!

I have created a bog-standard Menu in ASP.NET. It simply has four *normal* links from a *normal* **Web.Sitemap** file. I have styled it by referring to its **ID** via an **external style sheet**. Everything has been styled normally, EXCEPT an *ugly* **orange border**, which appears when a link is **clicked on**. I believe it is therefore *:active* when it has the orange border. So how do I **remove** this orange border?

Here is the relevant code:

In the **MasterPage**

```
<div id="Menu">
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" 
                Orientation="Horizontal">
            </asp:Menu>
                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ShowStartingNode="False" />
        </div>
```

From the **external stylesheet**:

```
#Menu
{
    height:20px;
    width: 780px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#Menu ul li
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 195px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
}
```

I have tried several different solutions which I would love to list to save your time, but I have probably forgotten the majority of them. Anyway... I could be making some stupid mistake which you will find immediately!

If you need more information then I will share whatever code, this is just a project I'm putting together for a few friends.

*Many thanks for your time,
JDWebs.*

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes the problem was just in chrome, but Ryan's solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try the following?

```
#Menu ul li a, 
#Menu ul li a:active {outline:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Like I said I was just beginning so I was not aware of the outline property; I thought it was border. I also forget the a! Once again thanks for your quick and correct response! Is there any other way I can repay you (e.g. ratings etc...)?

Comment: Haha, there's no need to repay me beyond a simple thank you.  I'm just glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

BTW: Use classes instead of IDs to style your menu. Using IDs is not a good idea if you use it together with ASP.NET because ASP.NET generates it's own ID for the tags with `runat="server"`.

Comment: Thank you for that tip - I didn't think that it made a difference!

Comment: + P.S. I viewed that question before but it was slightly different to the above apart from the outline which I didn't pick up on. Anyway, that's an interesting read.