# How do I remove border around a focused textbox

Tags: html, css

When we click on the textbox a border is appearing in Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove border around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Use `$outline:none;` in this manner:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

That way, it only applies when it's being used.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
textbox:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I used `texbox` just for illustration, in your code you should use element based on your html like `input, button, textarea` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `outline: none;` like:

```
input, textarea {
   outline: none;
}
```