# CSS label style Vaadin

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm trying to make inline editing in Vaadin. I think that good way to achieve that is styling 
text fields to make them look like labels, and switch to style of text field when focused.

Is it possible to style text field to look like label? How can I make it if it's possible?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want it to look like? I'd assume it's possible, but "label" is pretty broad unless you're talking about HTML '<label></label>'

Comment: Yeah... what look are you going for?

Comment: I have grid layout witch fields like: "name", "surname", "phone" etc. and values of them, I want to click on text, for example "John" and "John" should become editable text field, after focusing another one "John" should be plain text again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the Vaadin styles in your own theme. If you don't have a theme yet, create a directory under the VAADIN dir called `themes` and create a subdirectory in themes by the name of your theme, eg. mytheme.

**Vaadin 6:**

1. Call `setTheme("mytheme")` in your application class
2. Call `myTextField.setStyleName("labelstyle");` in your code
3. Create styles.css in your new theme directory.
4. Add the following in styles.css:

styles.css:

```
 @import "../reindeer/styles.css";

 .v-textfield-labelstyle {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
     border-color: #F5F5F5;
     border-image: none;
     border-left: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
     border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
     border-right: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
 }
```

**Vaadin 7:**

1. Add `@Theme("mytheme")` annotation in your UI class
2. Call `myTextField.setStyleName("labelstyle");` in your code
3. Create styles.**scss** in your new theme directory.
4. Add the following in styles.**scss**

styles.css:

```
 @import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";

 .mytheme {
    @include reindeer;

    .v-textfield-labelstyle {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
        border-color: #F5F5F5;
        border-image: none;
        border-left: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        border-right: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
}
```

1. Compile your theme by calling `java -cp '../../../WEB-INF/lib/*' com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler styles.scss styles.css` in your theme directory

This little trick will give you a Label-like TextField which turns into a normal TextField when focused.

Note that this will only work when using Reindeer theme and the default background color #F5F5F5. You'll have to tweak it a bit if you are using some other theme or the background color differs from the original.

Answer (score 1):

Text field is represented by this HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="v-textfield v-widget" tabindex="0" style="">
```

What about applying this: [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome) on "v-textfield v-widget" CSS?