# box-shadow doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: css

I can't make box shadow in chrome to work, I used webkit prefix but still I get orange frame around my  tag instead I should get gray shadow. This is working in all browsers except Chrome.

```
.loginForm input[type='text']:focus, .loginForm input[type='password']:focus,
.registerForm input[type='text']:focus, .registerForm input[type='password']:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
```

Comment: Property with prefix need to be used firstly

Comment: What does your HTML look like? A jsFiddle.net example is usually helpful with questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order in which you declare the box shadow properties - the unprefixed version should come last, like this:

```
.loginForm input[type='text']:focus, 
.loginForm input[type='password']:focus,
.registerForm input[type='text']:focus, 
.registerForm input[type='password']:focus{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;

    /* Remove the orange focus border */
    outline: 0;
}
```

The orange border is Chrome's default focus style and can be removed with `outline: 0` as shown above. More information can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397158/383609).

Answer (score 1):

This looks okay for me, but I think what you are seeing is the `outline` proprety on focus obscuring the shadow.

```
.selector {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VKkng/