# Yellow image border in Chrome after click

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, border

I am creating an 'add-this' sharing tool for my site. After clicking on the email icon, there is a yellow border around the email icon (only in chrome).

I would like to remove that yellow border. How can I?

Site: [here](http://proudeon.com/workshop/test.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the CSS `outline:none;` to your link.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `border-style:none;`

```
img {
    border-style:none;
}
```