# How to remove text area border when focused on?

Tags: html, css

I have managed to remove the text area border but I want it so the user cant see a border even when they click on it. This is my css as of yet.

```
.comments{
    border: 0 none #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I tried making the border transparent, I tried this also but it doesn't work either, also tried it with other attributes active etc.

```
.comments:focus{
    border: 0 none #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is it possible to remove the border when focused on?

The border isn't visible until the textarea is clicked on btw. So border none does work

Comment: wat's wrong with border:none

Comment: No effect when somebody clicks on the textarea, it removes it so you can't see it until its clicked @ManishMishra

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Comment: Apologies @Pbk1303 I did do about an hours research on it looking through sites and stack overflow but got no reward, problem was I was trying to remove the border when really I needed to remove the outline.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set  `outline:none` for the textarea.

```
.comments:focus{
    border: 0 none #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J68ja/)

Comment: Top man Sachin, that worked a treat. I'll accept that as the answer as soon as I'm able to, atleast I know I was on the right path.

Comment: may god bless you sir

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea, input { outline: none; }
```