# Getting rid of a blue box around button when pressed

Tags: html, css, styles

So, whenever I click on my button, this happens:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks guys. :)

Comment: Put a fiddle link! your LAN is not accessible to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you keeping your button inside `<a>` tag. If so use this code

```
a #btnid
{
border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Answered already (probably many times, but here's one example):  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397158/839847

Quoted here for convenience:

> This border is used to show that the element is focused (i.e. you can
>   type in the input or press the button with Enter). You can remove it,
>   though:
>
> ```
> textarea:focus, input:focus{
>     outline: 0;
> }
> ```
>
> You may want to add some other way for users to know what element has
>   keyboard focus though for usability.
>
> Chrome will also apply highlighting to other elements such as DIV's
>   used as modals. To prevent the highlight on those and all other
>   elements as well, you can do:
>
> ```
> *:focus {
>     outline: 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

panelMain.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

Button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

Adding this to your JFrame inherited class constructor will resolve the issue. The color does not have to be white, you can set it anything, just make sure the panel and button are of the same color. and please don't trust my answer too much because I too am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

To make this work for me in Chrome in 2021 I added this to my Site.css file:

```
.btn,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:hover {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```