# Border of a selected element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, border

I am not sure if is there a way to solve it. but my Google chrome creates a border when I click on a button, that calls a function.

[image]

The image bellows shows the blue border that is being showed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome

Comment: Thank you @sfletche I've searched but using wrong words..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

or for all elements

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: In practice, `outline: none` seems to be better supported by most browsers even though it should be identical to `outline: 0` in theory.