# How to prevent Google chrome style input border?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When a input (type=text) element get focus, Chrome styles it with a light blue color. Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `outline: none;` should prevent that.

http://jsfiddle.net/hm49g9a8/