# Cordova Text Font has White outline coming?

Tags: css, html, cordova

I am making a Cordova app. The Problem is my text has a white outline which doesn't look good.

I have a `div` with `background-color: yellow;`. Inside the `div`, I have written some text. The problem is that the text has a white outline. I want to remove that. Any Suggestions?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possibly a [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) issue?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed doesn't look like an outline issue. Try to set text-shadow to none.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
outline: 0;
```

to the css of your text element.

Source: [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

The person above seems to have a similiar issue.

Informative link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

Comment: `!important;` Ahhh :O Usually not the best idea to override the precedence. If it works when testing, it probably be a good idea to find which style is being overwritten and write a more specific one. `!important;` is a nasty habit to get into and makes for tough CSS challenges going forward.

Comment: That's true, but sometimes it's the only solution, some browsers have styles which can only be overwritten using !important