# Input field keeps lighting up. Can it be stopped?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to stop the input field from lighting up when it's selected with a little css?

Searched this up and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the following css: `outline: none;`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to `outline`

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

[How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)