# Syntax Error in PHP, unexpected '<'

Tags: php

I have a error problem with my code in php. can anyone help me to correct it!

```
<?php $query_tbl = "SELECT transaksi.id_transaksi, pelanggan.nama FROM transaksi, pelanggan ". 
            "WHERE transaksi.id_pelanggan = pelanggan.id_pelanggan ORDER BY id_transaksi";

        $list_tbl = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_tbl)
            or die('Error select table');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_tbl))
        { 
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_transaksi'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>';
            <form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
            </form>
            echo '</tr>';
        };?>
```

In Chrome i get this notif:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\delivery\pengiriman.php on line 33.

I don't know what is wrong because i am new with php.

And btw line 33 is

```
<form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
```

Comment: It would help if you'd show us the source-code of line 33 (the one you see in chrome when you click on the error)

Comment: <form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php"> is line 33

Answer (score 1):

there is some syntex error while putting HTML between PHP near your form tag

```
<?php $query_tbl = "SELECT `transaksi.id_transaksi`, `pelanggan.nama` FROM `transaksi`, `pelanggan` WHERE 
`transaksi.id_pelanggan` = `pelanggan.id_pelanggan` ORDER BY `id_transaksi`";

        $list_tbl = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_tbl)
            or die('Error select table');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_tbl))
        { 
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_transaksi'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>';?>
            <form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
            </form>
          <?php   echo '</tr>';
        };?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this more simple and neat code**

```
<?php
    $query_tbl = "SELECT transaksi.id_transaksi, pelanggan.nama FROM transaksi, pelanggan ". "WHERE transaksi.id_pelanggan = pelanggan.id_pelanggan ORDER BY id_transaksi";
    $list_tbl = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_tbl) or die('Error select table');
?>


<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_tbl)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nama']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can you use the `while():` - `endwhile;` syntax in vanilla PHP? Or is that only when you use an template engine?

Comment: i try this. and it works. but the button is placed above the table.

Comment: @MahfudMuhammad, that's because It's not in the `td` tags. Put it between them, and You should be fine

Comment: oh yeah! it works. thanks. but i one question now. the table is border='1', so the <td> make the button arounded by line. can the line around the button removed?

Comment: @MahfudMuhammad yes. For that you can remove the `border='1'` part, or [Fiddle around with the CSS Border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: @Mathlight i already removed it `border="1"` but the line still there.

Comment: @MahfudMuhammad then you have to take a look at the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and see what is creating the border and delete / override that part of the code

Comment: @MahfudMuhammad Hi, you can add the form inside <td> should be ok after that. about the line around the button, maybe you should check the css, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome

Comment: @Mathlight ofcourse can do that on all .php file extension

Answer (score 0):

You can't put HTML directly into PHP

```
<?php $query_tbl = "SELECT transaksi.id_transaksi, pelanggan.nama FROM transaksi, pelanggan ". 
        "WHERE transaksi.id_pelanggan = pelanggan.id_pelanggan ORDER BY id_transaksi";

    $list_tbl = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_tbl)
        or die('Error select table');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_tbl))
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id_transaksi'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>';
?>  <!-- here ends the PHP -->
        <form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
        </form>
<?php // here begin PHP again
        echo '</tr>';
    };?>
```

Comment: I try it but i get this now: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\delivery\pengiriman.php on line 34" Line 34: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />

Comment: btw i want to create edit button in every row of my table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the php then start it again. Try this:

```
<?php $query_tbl = "SELECT transaksi.id_transaksi, pelanggan.nama FROM transaksi, pelanggan ". 
            "WHERE transaksi.id_pelanggan = pelanggan.id_pelanggan ORDER BY id_transaksi";

    $list_tbl = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_tbl)
        or die('Error select table');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_tbl))
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id_transaksi'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['nama'] . '</td>';
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="pengiriman-input.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id_transaksi']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Kirim" />
        </form>
    <?php
        echo '</tr>';
    };?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above snippet you are opening a php tag in line 1 and have thought of closing it at last line. Between these two tag you cannot write the html script for creating form, as you are doing, in a php file.

It will be taken as a php script instead of html script and php compiler don't understands html tags.

Create the form tag as a php string variable and echo it as you are doing in the lines above.