# How to set the border per side for an input box?

Tags: html, css, forms, input

The `input-box` comes with an outline that can be set to `0`.
It will then show an ugly border around it.

This border can be set to `none` as well, leaving the input box without a border.

However I'd like to put a border only on the top and bottom of the input box, but can't get it done. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this to your input element

```
input {
    border: 1px solid #000; /* this will give the input 1px black border all around */
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

Should do it.

---

Or alternatively, you can go

```
input {
    border: 0; /* resets default border */
    border-top: [your border styling];
    border-bottom: [your border styling];
}
```

Comment: thanks @kevinMario! Can the border style be adjusted as well? (like the pixels etc.) nothing seems to work.

Comment: set border-top and border-bottom property.

Comment: Border styles are one of **{solid,double,dashed,dotted,ridge,groove,inset,outset}** try them out !

Answer (score 1):

Just do this if you want to use the provided border..

```
input {
  border-left:0px;
  border-right:0px;
}
```

If you don't want that than use..

```
input {
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  border-left:0px;
  border-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the borders, there's also an **outline** added by the browser.

You can do

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

or even

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

to disable this line.

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397158/3510872