# cell border color is behaving weird

Tags: html, css

So the color of my cells borders are behaving strange. I've done border-color:#4A90E2; but the color switches in the middle of the border. I have added image of what happens.[image]

My ccs code for the cell is

```
.tre{
color:black;
width:613px;
height:20px;
position:absolute;
top:180px;
left:-160px;
font-size:40px;
font-family:avenir;
}
.fyra{
background-color:white;
width:463px;
height:51px;
position:absolute;
top:230px;
left:-160px;
border-radius:10px;
border-color:#4A90E2;
display:inline-block;
font-size:30px;
font-family:avenir;
}
```

my php code for the cell is

```html
<tr> 
    <td class="tre">Efternamn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> <input class="fyra"type="text" name="efternamn"></td>
</tr>
```

How can I fix this, I want the border to be one color.

---

[image]

Image for Fast Snail. This is what happens when I click in the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
border:2px solid #4A90E2;
```

instead of

```
border-color:#4A90E2;
```

default border style is `inset` .it looks like 2 color border
example

https://jsfiddle.net/m0p05q25/

Comment: can you please help me, how can I change the color of the shadow that appears when you press in the cell. It is rectangle, I want it to be like the cell.

Comment: if you go in to the fiddle you linked, then press inside the box, there appears a rectangle shadow around the box,

Comment: How can I make that rectangle shadow to adjust to the box

Comment: @Markus what is your web browser ?

Comment: my web browser is safari

Comment: opps i don't have that one.i think it's browser dependent . i can't see a shadow

Comment: I just want it to not be a rectangle, but to adjust to the box

Comment: I added a picture in a new answer

Comment: now when I do outline:none; it goes away, but I would like it to stay just adjust to the box

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.fyra` class :

```
border-style: solid;
```

Comment: can you please help me, how can I change the color of the shadow that appears when you press in the cell. It is rectangle, I want it to be like the cell.

Comment: You can do the following with : `input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
}` [Check this answere for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3397158/4843666)

Comment: alright thx that worked, but if I wanted it to stay just adjust to the box how should I then do?

Comment: Then you just add your style as you want to get the same result. As an example :
`input[type=text]:focus { 
  outline: none; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);  
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}`