# paper-input broken with odd halo

Tags: polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I have a Polymer application for which I am getting the following warning:

> /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.

So I did a `bower update` to my components. Here is the relevant part of my bower.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.1.0",
  "iron-input": "PolymerElements/iron-input#~1.0.6",
  "neon-animation": "PolymerElements/neon-animation#~1.0.7",
  "google-map": "GoogleWebComponents/google-map#~1.1.4",
  "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#~1.0.5",
  "iron-form": "PolymerElements/iron-form#~1.0.11",
  "Autolinker.js": "~0.22.0",
  "paper-checkbox": "PolymerElements/paper-checkbox#~1.1.3",
  "masonry": "^4.1.0"
}
```

and now I am getting another error,

> This file is deprecated. Please use iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html, and one of the specific dom-modules instead

which was inserted directly as a `console.warn()` when polybuilding my application. No, it does not say what "this file" is that's deprecated.

Not sure if these warnings are in any way related to the new issue I've created for myself by doing the `bower update`, namely that the `paper-input` in my modal form no longer works and has a weird halo around it:

[image: weird halo]

Any ideas what is causing the error? Is it related to the warnings?

Comment: Please define "paper-input no longer works"

Comment: And the *halo* looks like focus outline. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz `paper-input` can no longer be selected or typed into. And the halo is not a normal featured of a focused `paper-input`.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your bower-components folder and running bower install again?