# How can i remove the extra border when click on the text-box?

Tags: html, css, search-box

```css
.search-box-border{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
.search-box{
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border-color:green;
}
li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<li class="search-box-border">
  <form role="search" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="search-box">
  </form>
</li>
```

In the above code I'm trying to create a text-box with a  `border-color` of green .but I faced some problems and i would like to resolve that.

1. I created the text box with a green border,but which is displayed as half black and half green(probably shadow),i want to remove this.
2. when click on the box there appear one extra border with ash colour,i want remove that one
   (probably the remains of the text-box),
   how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
border-color:green;
```

with

```
border: 1px solid green;
```

```css
.search-box-border{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
.search-box{
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  outline: none;
}
li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<li class="search-box-border">
  <form role="search" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="search-box">
  </form>
</li>
```

Comment: it removes the first issue..,i wish you can also fix the second issue too.

Comment: when click on the box there appear one more border with ash colour,i want remove that one.

Comment: I'm not getting any border on click.. which browser are you using?

Comment: May be this issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome  .. use `outline: none;`

Comment: chrome,are you don't see an ash colour border?,it appears  when click on the text box

Comment: @White Maskers I guess you're facing the one @cjmling has suggested. Check my answer now. You just have to add this part of the code `outline: none;` to get after that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding outline as none will fix the issue.

```
.search-box {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border-color: green;
}
```