# Remove the highlight in bootsrap datepicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker version 1.6.4. I wanted to remove the
Blue higlight as shown in the image below.

[image: Blue highlight to be removed]

I have done the following CSS codes: `outline: 0; outline: none;` but it does not work on Google chrome. I've tried to test it in different browser and I dont see the blue highlight. Is there a Chrome-specific CSS that I could use to solve my problem?

Comment: what are tried code ? please  insert your questions  or  js Fiddle

Comment: This has already been answered on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this to the input element of datepicker. I can't see what class it has or how to access it because you didn't provide any code.

So simply apply this css to this input and it should resolve your problem:

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
```

Example:

```css
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="noselect" value="10/12/2016"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do. See the inline demo. I would suggest, instead of removing the completion selection highlight, just change the background or font color.

```css
.noselect::selection {
  color: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<h6>Sample</h6>

<input class="noselect" type="text" value="11/05/1988" />
```