# How to remove an <input> border?

Tags: html, css, html-input

I use an `<input>` for which I style the border:

```css
input {
  font-size: 300%;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

The problem is that once `<input>` has the focus, a tiny blue border appears:

[image]

I do not see it anywhere in DevTools so I believe it is a property of `<input>` itself, which was not intended to have rounded borders (wildly guessing)

**Is it possible to get rid of it?**

Comment: Please do not remove the `outline` property - http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Comment: @ovokuro: why? (is this because of the accessibility mentioned in an answer?)

Comment: Yes, keyboard users depend on the feedback that it provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it with `outline:none`, but it creates [accessibility issues](http://outlinenone.com/).

```css
input {
  font-size: 300%;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the accessibility point (good link). I will keep it like this then.

Answer (score 0):

that should work for you

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

but this is already more detailed in the following link

[How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```