# HTML ugly borders around divs on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a navigation made from divs. When you click on a div, the requested page is loaded into another div.

My problem now is, that safari and chrome are making an ugly border around any div i click.

[image]

How does one get rid of this border?

I've already tried

```
*, *:focus, *::-moz-focus-inner, div, div:focus, div::-moz-focus-inner {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

But it does not work...

Comment: share the html code

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome

Comment: @Hilfsschueler have you tried  `{outline: none; border:none}` ?

Comment: @Vishnu

I already tried the following:
    *, *:focus, *::-moz-focus-inner, div, div:focus, div::-moz-focus-inner 
    {
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one...

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the outline in your CSS:

```
.that-div {
  outline: 0;
}
```

(Or outline: none).