# How To Remove Orange Border Around Input

Tags: css, firefox, focus, border

It's work only in Chrome:

```
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

or

```
input:focus{
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: This is working, but I do not like it. It creates a bevel when the user enters something *:focus { background:none;}

Comment: how to remove orange border?

Answer (score 0):

```css
input:required {
    box-shadow: none;
}

input:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;

}
```

```html
<input type='email'  placeholder='email' required  />
```