# IE11 Broken or over-spill border/outline

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

```css
textarea {
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

This issue is really bugging me and still can't find a solution, why is my `textarea` broken or showing black or blue outline randonmly? I have no issues in Chrome. It can be removed by mouse click... this is how it is in IE below gif:

Broken outline or border:

[image]

Comment: Yeah no difference. I'll post my full CSS.

Comment: not full only related to the textarea

Comment: The css posted makes quite a different textarea than shown in the `.gif`

Comment: Sorry I have the current one now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Comment: @AdeelImran Two things: if you're going to close a question as a duplicate, make sure you are not using a question as a target that has also been closed as a duplicate. Also, that question is specifically about a problem in Chrome. This question specifically says there is *no* problem in Chrome.

Comment: @TylerH understood, thank you. I'll keep that in mind next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the textarea gets the `focus` as soon as you select it/click on it. You can prevent that by applying a regular `border` setting to `textarea:focus`, but this is not recommended, since the highlighting of the focused element is essential for the accessibility of websites in general.

(Depending on the browser you also might want to add `outline: none` and `box-shadow: none`) since different browsers handle the focus highlighting differently.

```css
textarea:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi @Johannes many thanks for your reply. I have just commented on SuperDJ's answer and advised that the actual code I had to add to my CSS to fix is: **overflow: 'hidden'**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following, it makes sure the user can't highlight the textarea.

```css
textarea {
    outline: 0;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks @SuperDJ for your help. My CSS was in fact not specifying a hidden overflow which caused the isseu. Why? I don't really know. The code I used to resolve it: **overflow: 'hidden'**.

Comment: @ASF you should add that as a answer and mark it as such. that will help other users

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found that fixed the issue in the end was adding this to the CSS:

```
overflow: 'hidden'
```

I hope this helps others in the future.