# How to disable blue border line in IonInput fields?

Tags: html, css

I want to disable the blu border line in IonInput of IonicV2.

I try to add some CSS from the net but id doesn't work

```html
<ionlist 
    id="list" 
    nolines 
    style="margin-top:150px;margin-bottom:15px" 
    visible
>
    <ionitem 
        id="usernameItem" 
        detail="none" 
        wraptext="false" 
        sticky="false" 
        type="default" 
        style="display:flex;position:relative;top:0px;bottom:0px;border-top:1px none rgb(222, 222, 222);border-bottom:1px none rgb(0, 0, 0);height:68px"
    >
        <ioninput 
            id="username" 
            style="display:flex;border-bottom:1px solid rgb(225, 39, 39)" 
            label="Username" 
            labelposition="floating" 
            type="username"
        ></ioninput>
    </ionitem>
    <ionitem 
        id="passwordItem" 
        type="default" 
        style="border-top:1px none rgb(0, 0, 0);border-bottom:1px none rgb(222, 222, 222)" 
        detail="none" 
        wraptext="false" 
        sticky="false"
    >
        <ioninput 
            id="password" 
            style="display:flex;border-bottom:1px solid rgb(225, 39, 39)" 
            labelposition="floating" 
            label="Password" 
            type="password"
        ></ioninput>
    </ionitem>
</ionlist>
```

Actually, the second ionInput field doesn't show the blue border line but I don't know why

Comment: Perhaps you are indicating on the outline of the element? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome

Comment: @NickVanLoocke I see but my question is for IonInput field

Comment: Regard, for my understanding, ion also generates HTML, so there is not different between an 'ioninput' or the html input?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the outline of the ioninput. Just add `outline: none` to the certain element (in this case ioninput).

Comment: I try but it doesn't work, then i choose to use bootstrap element