# How to remove black border from option when hover in chrome 83

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I update my chrome browser to `83` and saw the `option tag` and it looks ugly, It shows the black border when hovering in option.

I tried

```
option {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

option:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```css
option {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

option:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

but still no luck!! why? I don't know.

I want to remove that black border because In my project it looks ugly.

**MY NEED**

I need same result as previous select and option tag have.

Comment: When you select any option tag, `select tag` shows weird black border and change its `border-radius`

Comment: This black border is now ubiquitos in chrome. Not only in the options. I'm also searching for a way to get rid of it. At least for myself. Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-focus-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome ?

Comment: Yes I tried all ways but still not working

Comment: The focus outline styles were updated for accessibility reasons: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

Comment: @Benni, I know that UI is changed in chrome 83 but I want to remove that black border, is it possible?

Comment: Not only it's UGLY, but it's even implementation-broken - If you quickly hover and unhover an option and start scrolling the page, the options do not close :) I cannot believe this ended up in production.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes you 100% right

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins I tried that and it works great in chrome. But those ugly black lines remain on the option elements. Also they have a small height...

Comment: Just notice this update today and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Just to make a remark, the outline workaround doesn't seem to work any longer (Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit).
OS: Windows / Linux - didn't test it on other OS though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome showing black border on focus state for button user agent styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992025/google-chrome-showing-black-border-on-focus-state-for-button-user-agent-styles)

Answer (score 10):

I found this [thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en)

> Sadly, there's not a bug or something similar. It is a new feature

I hope that they will change their implementation in chrome's next release.

:focus-visible, :focus and :hover are not working for the `option` in this chrome version

Comment: I hope it will optional in chrome 84 

Comment: Thanks for answering a question but the problem is it will disable all-new feature given by chrome and If I talk about 2nd answer it will require an extension for change

Answer (score 10):

in Chrome 84, the black border around select option item doesn't seem to appear when hovering. Now changing css outline rule is the easiest way to remove black border for focusable input.

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**#Problem solution:**

### Go to below link or copy paste chrome url tab and hits enter.

**chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh**

and **Disabled** Web Platform Controls updated UI
[image]

Comment: That answer is already given above, don't give the same answer as Maria given.

Comment: This actually helped me alot. I dont have to open any 3rd party links ...

Answer (score 5):

This is an experimental feature.
You could try disabling this flag: chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh 
Apparantly the 83+ version of chrome changed how forms are rendered / handled.

Comment: That answer is already given above, don't give the same answer as Maria given.

Comment: Did she mention how to turn it off. Don't jump the gun on down votes. I dont mind downvotes but I added something to the context.

Comment: I don't even mention about the downvote and I didn't downvote your question, I just give the information, please don't repeat the same answer because your answer and Maria thread answer is exactly copy cat, so don't copy-paste answers from another site

Comment: This is not a solution from the developer's point of view.
This only work if you don't like to see it as a user.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that helps is css style for element: `outline: none;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set outline:none in select tag css property

Comment: This answer does not add anything useful to the question. There is an answer like that already.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
*, *:focus, *:hover {
    outline: none;
}

select {
    border: 0px none;
    border-radius: 0.001px; /* this value must be greater than 0, otherwise it won't work */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this people is not understanding the problem...
let me help you with this.

The solution is this, just add this property to your base css class:

```
.your-select-class {
    border: 0.5px solid #D1D5DB;
    outline: none; // this removes the border line 
}
```

And then if your want to change the properties in base of events you can do this:

```
.your-select-class {
    border: 0.5px solid #D1D5DB;
    outline: none;
    &.focus: { 
       // To this you can add a condition with the event "onfocus" and
       // then change the css properties. In this case, i'm using sccs.
       border: 0.5px solid #29ABE2;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(41, 171, 226, 0.5);
    }
    &.selected: {
       // Same than the other, but with onchange method
       border: 0.5px solid #D1D5DB;
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(122, 185, 211, 0.8);
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to You and Google
2. Accessibility
3. Go to: Show a quick highlight on the focused object
   turn off
   problem solved.

Answer (score -3):

Changing the colour of the border seems to remove the black hover state

Comment: No, that's wrong, please check before answering any question