# Google Chrome showing black border on focus state for button user agent styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently i was working on a web design project, and noticed something odd, after the last Google Chrome update. The default border style(user agent style) for button is changed, and which is looking visually annoying to me.

**Is there any method to modify/restore the default browser styles, i.e., user agent styles permanently?**

here are some images of the problem:
[image: self developed web page button]

[image: state of border color on click/focus]

**i have also checked other websites and even google**
[image: browsing on google images]

[image: other example]

**also checked the dev tool, found this border styles applied on the focus state of the button**
[image: also checked the dev tool, found this border styles applied on the focus state of the button]

Comment: Could the black line be a border, outline, shadow etc. ? You could try setting each of these to `none` for the button and see if the line disappears.

Comment: Hi @Run_Script yes i can override it easily, but i have to do it every time i create a new website/project. its like adding one more declaration in resetting the browser's default margin and padding from universal selector. Is there any method to alter the css of google chrome?

Comment: This totally destoyed my app and looks horrible. But I guess its overridable but for all customers that do not want to upgrade it sucks :(

Comment: @JGoodgive i think chrome should rollback this visual update for focus/active state on elements, noticed there are other changes in appearance too like, changed style of default date picker calendar, new checkbox design, appealing checkbox for style rules in devtool inspector

Comment: This is has been there recently only on Chrome and Linux. Chromium still looks good but Chromium has some color issue though. The website that used to look good one month before, now it is looking with black borders !

Comment: The focus style is actually a double outline black and white so that it is visible on any background. It's largely for accessibility as their prior blue blur outline was inaccessible. This current version is very accessible - https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

Comment: yes this is very accessible, but it should be presented as add on feature. not by default enabled feauture

Comment: March 2021. "The new :focus-visible pseudo-class is applied any time that an element receives focus and the browser determines via heuristics that displaying a focus indicator would be beneficial to the user." https://web.dev/style-focus/#use-:focus-visible-to-selectively-show-a-focus-indicator. Today, I went to save via [CTRL+S] about 50 google's cached web pages (OVH servers burned down 2 days ago, 150,000 websites down). Now I have this **focus indicator** activated an NO WAY NOR HINT on how to desactivate it. Disable `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh` fails.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This is because the new chrome update
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/nic83#forms

you can override black outline in most cases by

```
*,*:focus,*:hover{
    outline:none;
}
```

and you can see this article

https://web.dev/style-focus/#use-:focus-visible-to-selectively-show-a-focus-indicator

if you want to remove outline just for mouse user.

Comment: this style will be useful for new projects, need to think about those which are already done. i think google should disable this new style feature by default, which is currently enabled automatically. it will be good if user has to turn this new feature manually by himself with this link 
flag: chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh

Comment: yes i'm agree with you this will cause many problem to users and developers , google must back all old styles because not all of them you can modify it by css like checkbox or select options it's have ugly blue background

Comment: not all changes are annoying, some of them are looking nice. but this should not be enabled by default and automatically.

Comment: This is bad for accessibility. There are plenty of sighted keyboard only users and taking away focus styles is problematic.

Comment: That fix doesn't work, unless you include their polyfill (https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible) and then even that doesn't work on <option>'s...

Comment: @Jason Enabling "new styles" by default is problematic, not disabling them with CSS. Every web designer who sees this black border would demand a web dev to fix it. If it was opt-in, nobody would know and users with sight issues could enjoy black borders. Now these black borders just become a "bug" in an issue tracker, just like borders for images in links in IE. Either way, as someone who does use focus and could enjoy these borders, I find control focus in Chrome barely usable anyway.

Comment: i also needed to add ```!important``` to make it work.

Answer (score 24):

You could try disabling this flag: `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh`

Apparently the 83+ version of chrome changed how forms are rendered / handled:
https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html

Here is a relevent Google Support page which links to the blog post above:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en

Comment: i think google should rollback this update, as this solution is limited to my machine/system/only. The end-user for websites also have to update this setting in their systems too.

Comment: Or maybe google should just put a different color rather than black, and make it like the other blue that it had before? Well, that's the easy fix haha.

Comment: for any Google Chrome end-user (those who just want to see old style), disabling `form-controls-refresh` works.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the Google Support page you speak of?

Comment: Hey James. Here you go https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en. Although I can't find the original solution now.

Comment: @GaganDeep Thank you. I've edited your answer to include the relevent links.

Answer (score 18):

The issue isn't Chromium's new contrasting focus ring, it's the default behavior across browsers that clicking triggers the focus ring.

The focus ring appears on click when the `<button>` appearance is altered or receives `tabindex` attribute.

Accessibility is a must and the new contrasting black and white focus ring is a great step forward. However there are developers (including me) that don't want the focus ring to be present when using the mouse.

#### Solutions

1. `:focus-visible` css pseudo selector. Supported on all modern browsers [MDN Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#browser_compatibility)

```css
/*
  This will hide the focus indicator if the element receives focus via the mouse,
  but it will still show up on keyboard focus.
*/

button:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
 outline: none;
}
```

2. [focus-visible polyfill](https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible)

```css
/*
  This will hide the focus indicator if the element receives focus via the mouse,
  but it will still show up on keyboard focus.
*/
.js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}
```

if you're using a framework that overrides classes, use the focus visible attributes.

```css
[data-js-focus-visible] :focus:not([data-focus-visible-added]) {
  outline: none;
}
```

Keep in mind that for mobile users, if there's an element that triggers the soft keyboard to pop up, such as `<input type="text">`, it should have visual indication that it is focused.

Comment: Long clicking any button will **still show** the useless black rectangle.

Comment: @andreszs does this happen with the polyfill or the native pseudo class.

Comment: With both. However, I solved it by using `outline: 0px transparent !important;` as the propery for the :focus-visible CSS pseudo selector as suggested by @ThinkThank

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 way to handle it.

1. [configuration](https://www.askvg.com/fix-google-chrome-showing-thick-black-border-highlight-on-text-box-and-other-focused-items/#:%7E:text=Chromium%20team%20has%20updated%20form,displayed%20to%20highlight%20the%20focus.) in chrome which few has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992025/google-chrome-showing-black-border-on-focus-state-for-button-user-agent-styles/62098091#62098091).
2. Programmatically approach `outline: 0px transparent !important;` in style Or `outline: none !important;` Both have worked for me.

Since we can't force user to do configuration, I would suggest for second Option but it is long process If you have any shorter way tell us.

Comment: The most relevant answer

Comment: Finally a decent answer that actually works in all focusing scenarios. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me:

chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh

And disable this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFUdJ.jpg)

Comment: Yes, but for us developers (to which the question relates) this is not an acceptable solution. We can't tell every customer to make such "complicated" tasks - we have to stick to the default settings and try to change them ourself without client interaction. At least Google worked with Microsoft together on this. But still... kind of funny to see this "backward development" with flat design, homogene colors, everything rectangle and ugly looking outlines. Looks almost like Windows 1, DOS, Mac System Software, etc.

Comment: Of course, now ask every single user to do that as well, specially your boss to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

settings in chrome > Appearance > Show a quick highlight on the focused object.
Disable this option.

Comment: This worked for me as I was facing the issue during my application development I thought somethings wrong with my application but turns out it was working well with other application so fixed it by changing this option in chrome.

Comment: that's not what the question is about

Answer (score 1):

Go to chrome desktop browser

settings->Advanced->Accessibility->(Turn off)Show a quick highlight on the focused object

to avoid the shadow boxes when u click on your browser