# Unable to disable black border when using Tab key in Chrome [2022]

Tags: css, frontend, bootstrap-5

How to change that black box shadow color to another color when we switch nav tabs by using `Tab` key?

The code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs m-5">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT as of December 1st 2022 (Chrome v107.0.5304.121)**

It has nothing to do with Bootstrap. It [was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992025/google-chrome-showing-black-border-on-focus-state-for-button-user-agent-styles) before.

This happens because of the [Chrome v83 update](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-83/#forms) and [people don't like it](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en).

Seems like in the past it was possible to disable black border when using `↹` (i.e., `Tab` key) the following ways:

- disable `Web Platform Controls updated UI` ([source](https://www.askvg.com/fix-google-chrome-showing-thick-black-border-highlight-on-text-box-and-other-focused-items/#:%7E:text=Chromium%20team%20has%20updated%20form,displayed%20to%20highlight%20the%20focus.))
- disable this flag: `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61992025/google-chrome-showing-black-border-on-focus-state-for-button-user-agent-styles/62098091#62098091)) or
- go to `chrome://settings/accessibility` and disable `Show a quick highlight on the focused object` ([source](https://www.askvg.com/fix-google-chrome-showing-thick-black-border-highlight-on-text-box-and-other-focused-items/#comment-2756564)).

I was searching for a while, but was unable to disable black border in Chrome `v107.0.5304.121`.

Google says the black border is back and seems like there’s no way to get [rid](https://www.askvg.com/fix-google-chrome-showing-thick-black-border-highlight-on-text-box-and-other-focused-items/#comment-2757776) [of](https://www.askvg.com/fix-google-chrome-showing-thick-black-border-highlight-on-text-box-and-other-focused-items/#comment-2757788) [it](https://www.askvg.com/fix-google-chrome-showing-thick-black-border-highlight-on-text-box-and-other-focused-items/#comment-2757799).

Comment: when you click on TAB on keyboard, you can see, there is a black boxshadow / black border is there, i want to change that, when you click on tab button from your keyboard

Comment: I edited my answer with more explanation.