# How to make a button shaped as rectangle with 2 semi-circles at the side in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a button shaped like the below image, and I can't find any easy way to do it, nor does any of the libraries I have searched offers something like this, which is frankly surprising, as I would think that this is a rather common shape. Can anyone teach me how do I do this?

[image: button]

Comment: `border-radius:1em;`should be what you look for ;)

Comment: Assuming you have a fixed height of n-pixels you simply set border-radius to n/2 pixels :) Cheers

Comment: In JavaScript? That doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is CSS using border-radius.

```css
input[type="button"] {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Previous" />
```

The black outline you might be seeing (when you click the button) is a Chrome feature which can be disabled.  This is not something that (to my knowledge) can be fixed with `outline-style: none;`.  Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971404/how-to-remove-black-border-from-option-when-hover-in-chrome-83).

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property you are looking for is **border-radius**

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>Previous</button>
```