# cant remove blue highlight chrome on focus

Tags: html, css

when you click on search there's blue outline, for some reason css ignores these settings i've applied:

```
input:focus {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  outline-style: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline-color: transparent !important;
  outline-style: none !important;
  border:none !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
.help-center .hc-search-form:focus-within{
   border: 0 none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outline: none; on focus`

[How to remove focus border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-focus-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Be carefull for people who navigate with keyboard, it can be usefull

Comment: I agree, always make _something_ happen on focus. Even if it's a background change or anything, make something happen. Anyone who uses the `tab` button will have difficulty finding what they are selecting if it is not clearly marked. gov.uk does this very well, and so does bbc.co.uk/bitesize. Both these sites put thick outlines around the focused elements. That's very good for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code: `* { outline: none !important; }`