# Border Around Text Input When Clicked in React Native on Web

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am using React Native and TextInputs. There is a border around the TextInput when I click on it. When I click off, the border disappears. This does not happen on Android, but it happens on web. Below are some images. How can I get rid of this border?

When not clicked:

[image: 2]

When clicked:

[image: 1]

Browser: Chrome 84 
OS: Windows 10 
Expo Version: 3.26.1 
React Native Version: 4.12.0 
Nodejs Version: v12.18.3 
Npm Version: 6.14.6

Minimum Reproducible Example: https://snack.expo.io/@ketzoomer/dfbbdf

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Sign_Up extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    First Name:
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ paddingVertical: 0, borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 5 }}
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState({ firstName: firstName })}
                        placeholder="First Name"
                    />
                </Text> 
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Sign_Up;
```

What I tried:

I tried `outline: 0` and it did not work.

I tried `outlineWidth: 0` and it did not work.

I tried `borderWidth: 0`, and this did not work either.

Comment: use outline: none (only when platform is web) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397158/11380442

Comment: @SagharMirali I am getting error None is not defined. I will post code.

Comment: outline: 0 does not either

Comment: @SagharMirali btw I am using react native not react

Comment: I have used this before in react-native for web: outline: "none"

Comment: Why did it not work? Is it an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`outline: 'none'` will do the trick as mentioned by others in the comments. I tried with your `snack` and it seems to work. Here is the edit: https://snack.expo.io/ro0icIt!6. See below the code:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    First Name:
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ paddingVertical: 0, outline: 'none', borderBottomWidth: 1, marginLeft: 5 }}
                        value={this.state.firstName}
                        onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState({ firstName: firstName })}
                        placeholder="First Name"
                    />
                </Text> 
            </View>
        );
    }
```

I have also added below the video/gif:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is the answer I was looking for ( btw I can only award bounty in 13 hours so I will do that then ).

Comment: I didn't see there was no outline 

Comment: You saved my day :)

Answer (score 15):

`outline: 'none'` is no longer working. instead we can use

```
outlineStyle: 'none'
```

**Note:** *removing outline is not a good idea for accessibility if you don't have a better alternative for it.*
https://css-irl.info/accessibly-hiding-focus-outlines/

Comment: Confirming this still works in 2022

Comment: It works only in react native web. While building mobile app it says that outline is not a supported style.

Comment: Outline: 'none' may work for Chrome browsers... the required outline-style: none is needed for this to work on Safari. Still working Sept. 2023

Answer (score 1):

outline: 'none' is no longer working for React Native.

We can try:
`outlineStyle: 'none'`

But sometimes it could not work completly depending of the device. However in my case its working.