# Border not going away in the state :hover

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons, on which the folliwing css has been applied:

```
    display: flex;
    height: 43px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
}

.reset, .register{
    flex: 2;
    font-family: snes;
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.493);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: #FFF 0px 0px 5px, #FFF 0px 0px 15px, #1695CE 0px 0px 20px, #1695CE 0px 0px 30px, #1695CE 0px 0px 40px, #1695CE 0px 0px 50px, #1695CE 0px 0px 75px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

button.reset:focus{
    border: none;

}

.blank_space{
    flex: 1;
}
```

This is the html for both:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="reset" type="reset">Reset</button>
    <div class="blank_space"></div>
    <button class="register" type="submit">Register</button>
</div>
```

*Note: The blank space is just to divide the buttons using flex.

[image: Buttons in :focus state]

This is the result for the on focus state for the reset button (applies to the register button as well). I don't want the extra border. I have tried

```
button.reset:focus{
    border: none;
}
```

It didn't work.

Comment: That's the `outline` set by focus, not a border.

Comment: Relevant question: [How to remove focus border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-focus-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)