# removal of blue frame input field sap ui5

Tags: sapui5

I want to remove this blue color frame and also input focus frame . Do you have any idea how to remove this ?
[image]
Can anyone help me with this issue ? Kindly note this is not the border frame .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove focus border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-focus-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Theme without Frame like High Contrast White (just add [?sap-ui-theme=sap_hcw to your URL](https://ui5.sap.com/?sap-ui-theme=sap_hcw#/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputTypes))
But even this will have a Focus indicator, which is essential for accessibility.
If you **really** need to go without Frame and Focus you will have to create your own Theme (see [UI Theme Designer](https://ui5.sap.com/#/tools)).