# MUI Component: Blue Outline Appears in Text Field After Tab Switch?

Tags: material-ui

In my TextField components, I notice that if I switch to another browser tab, then switch back, a blue outline appears. Here's a gif file to demonstrate:

[image]

Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: I think you can remove the border from the textbox. Here's a reference link for that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397158/11223414

Comment: Hmmm.... if it's a Chrome thing, maybe I should just leave it.

Comment: It's not a chrome thing. You can try to add some styles like `outline: none` or `border: none`, etc for the focus pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

That is a focus ring to indicate to the user where the focus is. I would strongly discourage you from removing it, because it would lead to a bad experience for users who require assistive technology—they wouldn't know where the focus is at on the page.

Comment: I'm curious why the focus ring isn't present when you initially click into the text box. It only appears if you switch to a new window and switch back. Is that the expected behavior?